# javascript: call method on dynamically generated object name

Tags: javascript

How would one call a method on a dynamically generated name? This is a case where I am passing the object name into a function and calling a method on that object. Something like this, where type is the name of the object I want to execute the method on:

```
function doSomething(type) {
    type.someMethod();
}
```

Note that I do not want to pass the object into the function.

Comment: if you don't want to pass the object.
you can try using eval

Comment: try eval(type + ".method()");

Comment: Depends on the scope of the object. If it's global window[type].someMethod () will work, but using a passed in object name is typically a terrible idea because it's prone to error. It would be best to pass in an actual object.

Answer (score 1):

If your object is global, you could do this :

```js
var global = global || window;

function doSomething(type) {
    global[type].someMethod();
}

var myObject = {
  someMethod : function () { console.log("calling someMethod") }, 
};
  
  
doSomething("myObject");
```

Answer (score 1):

First, it is not clear what object that "type" belongs to.  I'm guessing this is in scope, maybe something like this:

```
var typeObjects = {
    type1: {
      doSomething: function(){..},
      ..
    },
    type2: {
      doSomething: function(){..},
      ..
    },
    ..
}
```

Then, your function becomes the following:

```
function doSomething(typeName) {
    typeObjects[typeName].someMethod();
}
```

And then you would call it like so:

```
doSomething('type1');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to eval the object name or method.

```
eval(type)['someMethod']();
```

or

```
eval(type + '.someMethod()');
```

Also if your object is at *window* scope, you can do

```
window[type].someMethod();
```

Comment: Probably because you don't need to use `eval` to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass a variable name to a function, consider instead passing a property name of a predetermined object, so that your function is not unsafely accessing arbitrary objects from its scope with `eval()`, which is a bad practice for both security and performance reasons.

```js
var myObject = {
  foo: { someMethod () { console.log('fooObj') } },
  bar: { someMethod () { console.log('barObj') } }
}

function doSomething (property) {
  if (myObject.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
    myObject[property].someMethod()
  }
}

doSomething('foo')
doSomething('bar')
doSomething('nil') // does nothing
```